# Why is my right side column's first div acting weird?(I have same styles for all)

Tags: html, css, position

The very first div element which has class "container", doesn't position itself the same as other div elements inside the "mom" div.
I purposly made everything colorful so the dimensions can be seen easily.
I want to float all divs to right but I need their text to be centered.
My left div container,"mom1" doesn't have the same problem.
Only the right div container, "mom" misbehaves.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
```

**CSS**

```
<style>
 .image.main
 {
    background-color:yellow;
    width:99%;
    position: fixed;
    top:108px;
    z-index:-1;
    text-align: center;
 }

 .image.main img 
 {
   background-color:red;
   height:505px;
   opacity: 0.8;
   z-index:-1;
 }

 .mom
{
   background-color:gray;
   width: 330px;
   height: 500px;
   float: right;
   overflow: auto;
   text-align:center;
}
 .mom1
{
   background-color:gray;
   width: 330px;
   height: 500px;
   float: left;
   overflow: auto;
   text-align:center;
   color:white;
}
.container
{
background-color:green;
}
.container2
{
background-color:pink;
}
.container3
{
background-color:white;
}

.shapes
 {
   text-align: center;
 } 
 header, footer{
   background-color:#982202;
   color: white;
   height:38px;
 }
 footer {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index:-1;
 }
</style>
```

**HTML**

```
 <head>
  <title>Jared Gilmore is Lovely</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta name="description" content="About Jared Gilmore">
  <meta name="keywords" content="Jared Gilmore, teenage, actor, talented, modern, comedy">
  <meta name="author" content="Meghedi Mirbekian">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
</head>

<body>
<header>
<h1>Jared Gilmore</h1>
</header>

<div class="shapes">
<pre>&hearts;     &#9824;     &hearts;     &#9824;     &hearts;     &#9824;     &hearts;     &#9824;     &hearts;     &#9824;     &hearts;     &#9824;     &hearts;     &#9824;     &hearts;     &#9824;     &hearts;     &#9824;     &hearts;     &#9824;     &hearts;     &#9824;     &hearts;     &#9824;     &hearts;     &#9824;     &hearts;     &#9824;     &hearts; 
</pre>
</div>


<div class="image main">  
<picture>
  <source media="(min-width: 650px)" srcset="..\images\DciZZIsXkAA1bYw.jpg">
  <source media="(min-width: 465px)" srcset="..\images\DcibzHLXkAA-vgV.jpg">
  <img src="..\images\gg.jpg" alt="Flowers" style="width:auto;">
</picture>
</div>
<div class="mom"> 
<div class="container">
<h2>About Jared Gilmore</h2>
<h4>Personal life</h4>
<h4>Carrier Life</h4>
</div>

<div class="container2">
<h2>About Jared Gilmore</h2>
<h4>Personal life</h4>
<h4>Carrier Life</h4>
</div>
<div class="container3">
<h2>About Jared Gilmore</h2>
<h4>Personal life</h4>
<h4>Carrier Life</h4>
</div>
</div>

<div class=mom1>
<p>
Jared Gilmore is amazing
  talented
    and amazing
</p>
<p class="display">Gilmore is amazing!
</p>

<p>Isn't he cute?</p>

<iframe class="iframe"  width="320" height="150" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/W1A2mXbmxuM" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>

<p>Creativity takes courage<br><cite>-Matisse</cite></p>
<footer></footer>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has to do with effect bootstrap css is having.

Try adding width: 330px to your container class, like this:

```
.container
{
background-color:green;
width: 330px;
}
```

Please see image: is what you are trying to achieve?[image]

Comment: @aly sa You could also remove the bootstrap CDN if you are not using it.

Comment: sure! Thank you so much..let me try it

Comment: hmm.. afraid I don't understand what you are looking for then.  Check this: https://jsfiddle.net/qwj226h3/1/

Comment: yes this on is the one i want ..thanks alot..please don't remove it..let me see

Comment: @aly sa If this was helpful please vote as the correct answer.

Comment: This is amazing..I'm very thankfull! What" !important" ? Is it just a comment?

Comment: !important overrides any previous CSS rule and may not be necessary in this circumstance.  @aly sa ... I am going to have google Jared :)

Comment: hey is there anyway I can contact you directly if I have questions?

Comment: I would be happy to help.  Maybe someone else can chime in with how to chat - I don't know.  If you @my name I will see it and attempt to help whenever I can.

Comment: awww ok..lol i didn't know that stuff..new here..thanks a lot anyways!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding display: inline; to the container class?
It's quite hard to interpret your question.

Comment: the first div in mom container stands differently from two other divs below it. I need them to position themselves vertically below each other.

Comment: where should i add position:inline to make them position exactly on top of each other?